# Структуры, обращение к элементам структуры

Tags: c++, struct

Здравствуйте, как правильно обращаться к элементам структуры.

```
struct A{
 int a;
 int b;
}
struct B{
 A obj[n];
}
```

Что бы вывести в цикле информацию нужно сделать так?

```
 for (int i=0;i<n; i++){
  cout << B.A[i].a << B.A[i].b;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала вам нужно создать объект структуры. Например,

```
B b;
// ...
```

и затем после инициализации элементов структуры уже можно выполнить цикл

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    std::cout << b.obj[i].a << b.obj[i].b;
}
```